# Sending Email to multiple recipients in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, .net-3.5, system.net.mail

I'd like to ask if sending email to multiple recipients in vb.net is possible?

What I mean here is I want to create a program that sends email to multiple recipients, unlike the usual program which the email address , the subject and other email attributes are hard coded, what I want is hopefully the email address, message body, is came from the database.

So basically if i will going to call a form to send the email, it will fetch the data from the database server providing me a list of recipients and their other details.

Can someone show me how to do that? I would be grateful if someone could show me how to do it. Thanks!

Comment: The same way you send to a single recipient.  What did you try?

Comment: i need the recipient email address is came from the database

Comment: have you managed to get the email address from the database yet? If not then you need to try that first

Answer (score 2):

It's to simple :

```
Public Function Snd(ByVal frm As String, ByVal tooo As List(Of String), _
                        ByVal pass As String, ByVal hst As String, _
                        ByVal sbj As String, ByVal bdy As String, _
                        ByVal lAtt As List(Of String)) As String


        Dim ml As New MailMessage()

        ml.From = New MailAddress(frm)
        For Each sA As String In tooo
            ml.To.Add(sA)
        Next

        ml.Subject = sbj
        ml.Body = bdy
        For Each sA As String In lAtt
            ml.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(sA))
        Next
        '"smtp.gmail.com" for gmail
        '"smtp.live.com"   for hotmail
        Dim SMTPServer As New SmtpClient(hst)
        SMTPServer.Port = 587
        SMTPServer.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(frm, pass)
        SMTPServer.EnableSsl = hst <> "smtp.mail.yahoo.com"

        Try
            SMTPServer.Send(ml)
            Return "Sent"
        Catch ex As SmtpException
            Return ex.Message
        End Try
        Return ""
    End Function
```

Check this : [sending email using smtp](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jv7eFcfWhWQ)

Comment: I'm sorry if you did not understand my question, basically I only want is to send messages to several email addresses from database. that's it.. I already know the code for sending email thru smtp.

Comment: Ok, what kind of database? SQL? what tech you use LINQ,  ADO.net? what table and fields?? show us some code to help you